# What values of $\lambda$ make $\{u, v, w\}$ linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've encountered a little trouble while solving this problem:

Let $\overrightarrow{u}=(\lambda,1,0),\space\overrightarrow{v}=(1,\lambda,1),\space\overrightarrow{w}=(0,1,\lambda)$.
Find all values of $\lambda$ which make {$\overrightarrow{u},\overrightarrow{v},\overrightarrow{w}$} a linearly dependent subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**My solution:**

As the linear dependent condition, I rewrite those vectors as a linear combination:

$\alpha\overrightarrow{u}+\beta\overrightarrow{v}=\overrightarrow{w}$

And I obtained these linear systems:

$\alpha\lambda+\beta=0\\
\alpha+\lambda\beta=1\\
\beta=\lambda$

Lastly, when I solved these linear systems, I found that $\lambda=0, \lambda=-1, \lambda=1$

I am confused with my own method and solution. Is someone can explain to me where did I go wrong? I will appreciate it. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Do you know about determinants?

Comment: You can visually check the answer here: https://www.math3d.org/zZIvcfPJN

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system of equation should be
$x\vec{u}+y\vec{v}+z\vec{w}=0$

accordingly you should get:-

$\begin{align}\lambda x+y=0\end{align}\\ x+\lambda y +z=0\\y+\lambda z=0$.

You have to find $\lambda$ such that these equation has atleast one non-zero solution.

To do that use cramer's rule and use the determinants. ( Otherwise you can reduce it to RREF but just evaluating the determinant is way easier in this case).

Take the determinant and equate it to $0$. This would correspond to having infinite solutions ( and hence a non-zero solution) to the system of equations represented by the vectors.

That is find $\lambda$ such that

$$\begin{vmatrix}\lambda &1&0\\ 1 &\lambda &1\\0&1&\lambda\end{vmatrix}=0$$.

The determinant is $\lambda(\lambda^{2}-2)$.

So the values of $\lambda=0,\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You made some mistake while solving the system, because its solutions are $(\alpha,\beta,\lambda)=(1,0,0)$, $(\alpha,\beta,\lambda)=\left(-1,\sqrt2,\sqrt2\right)$, and $(\alpha,\beta,\lambda)=\left(-1,-\sqrt2,-\sqrt2\right)$. Besides, this will give you only the cases in which $\vec w$ is a linear combination of $\vec u$ and $\vec v$. But it could also happen that $\vec u$ is a linear combination of $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ or that $\vec v$ is a linear combination of $\vec u$ and $\vec w$.

Comment: Thank you very much!